# Unable to dismiss MFMailComposeViewController, delegate not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am calling `MFMailComposeViewController` from a `UITableViewController`.
Problem is the delegate method is never called when I select *Cancel* or *Send* button in Mail compose window:

```
mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controllerdidFinishWithResult
```

Here is the table view class:

```
@implementation DetailsTableViewController
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section==0 && indexPath.row==4) {
        //SEND MAIL
        MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
            [controller setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Ref %@",[item objectForKey:@"reference"]]];
            [controller setMessageBody:@" " isHTML:NO]; 
            [controller setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[item objectForKey:@"email"]]]; 
            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        }
        [controller release];       
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controllerdidFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    // NEVER REACHES THIS PLACE
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    NSLog (@"mail finished");
}
```

The application doesn't crash. After the Cancel or Send button is pressed, the Compose Window stays on the screen with buttons disabled. I can exit application pressing Home key.

I am able to open other Modal Views form TableView but not MailCompose.

Answer (score 219):

Make sure you use

```
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

and not

```
controller.delegate = self;
```

Comment: `MFMailComposeViewController` is a subclass of `UINavigationController`. They do this so that you can implement the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` methods.

Comment: I think its only one view controller having different delegate, also troubled for some time Thanks mxg :)

Answer (score 14):

Your method signature is incorrect:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controllerdidFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
```

Should be:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
```

Comment: I believe this is just a typo in his question.

Answer (score 4):

Refer this article for full implementation :  http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/send-email-from-an-app

working code after making removing deprecated one :

```
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@interface SettingsTableViewController () <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate>

@end


@implementation SettingsTableViewController
// add default methods

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger sectionNum = indexPath.section;
    NSInteger rowNum = indexPath.row;
    if (sectionNum == 2 && rowNum == 1) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
            [controller setSubject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Invitation to Northstar app"]];
            [controller setMessageBody:@" " isHTML:NO];
//            [controller setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[item objectForKey:@"email"]]];
            //presentViewController:animated:completion:
            [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
        }
    }
}
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{        
    NSLog (@"mail finished");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

@end
```

Comment: This article is very helpful : http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/send-email-from-an-app

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem and was searching for a fix from past 2 days then I found a fix myself and you won't believe how minor it was.

In my case the view controller (say 'DetailsTableViewController' as per this question) from where I was presenting the `MFMailComposeViewController` is already being presented from some other view controller (say 'BaseViewController').

The issue was lying in the '`modalPresentationStyle`' of 'DetailsTableViewController' while presenting it from BaseViewController.

The moment I changed it from '`UIModalPresentationFormSheet`' to '`UIModalPresentationPageSheet`' (for that matter any thing other than '`UIModalPresentationFormSheet`') issue got resolved and mail controller delegate methods started firing as usual.

Note: I was already calling the below method in 'DetailsTableViewController' (for this example) so it didn't really matter for me which '`modalPresentationStyle`' I was using.

```
    - (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
    self.view.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```