# iOS: MFMailComposeViewController not getting closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I am using `MFMailComposeViewController` in my application to compose a feedback E-Mail. The `MFMailComposeViewController` gets displayed, but can't be closed.

Method used to open the `MFMailComposeViewController` modal window:

```
-(IBAction) feedbackBtnClicked:(id)sender {

    // Dismiss the Old View Controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];

    // Present the New View Controller
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mail setSubject:@"Sample Subject"];
        [mail setMessageBody:@"Here is some main text in the email!" isHTML:NO];
        [mail setToRecipients:@[@"example@mail.com"]];

        [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"This device cannot send email");
    }
}
```

Here is what happens, when clicking on the buttons:

**Senden (Send)** - The E-Mail gets sent, but the modal window stays open; clicking on that button multiple times results in sending multiple E-Mails without the modal window ever getting closed.
**Abbrechen (Cancel)** - Nothing happens

How to dismiss make sure the `MFMailComposeViewController` gets dismissed after clicking on those buttons?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918651/unable-to-dismiss-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-delegate-not-called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` method `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:`, and dismiss the mail view controller…

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller
                 didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```